# Importing 100MB XML file into my iPad application

Tags: ios, ipad

I've a 100MB xml file in which I've stored some data and I want to use these data in my iPhone app.

1. What's the most efficient way to store them into my iPad application ? Should I use Core Data and create a data model or should I just store the xml file ?
2. If the best solution is to import the xml file into a data model, how can I do it ? Should I run some objective code from my app once (just for importing it) ? I need some guidelines..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in storing this file, is that you'll need to package it into your application.
If you store it in core data, you'll need to bundle the db within your app.

Depending how much you need to access the data stored in your XML, you could probably create some kind of "XMLReader", but at this point, this may be easier to use CoreData so you can work with NSManagedObject in your application.

In both cases (reading directly from XML/store in core data) you need to parse your XML file and in result you'll have an array of dictionnaries or objects.
Parsing an XML file each time you need some elements in it can be memory and process consuming.

So I recommand: create a 3rd party app that will generate a DB file from your XML based on your data model.

Bundle this db file in your final application, and work with NSManagedObject

Comment: @vfloz ok, should I import the xml file in SQLLite and then copy the SQLListe database into the app ? Or should I use another technology ?

Comment: the best way is to use CoreData that is an abstraction layer over SQLite. So just create an importer (in obj-c) with core data that will import your XML file to a CoreData generated DB, then bundle this db into your app (you have access to the simulator file in ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/iPhoneSimulator...

Comment: but use CoreData to make the import, otherwise your DB won't be usable in your app

Comment: @vfloz oh ok, but then, this third party app is actually an ios app I'm using just to import the data, right ? And then I move the generated CoreData DB file into my app, I guess.

Comment: yes!that's it! That should make the trick! After you can use this parser if you wanna make some additions to the DB from internet too via an XML feed!

Comment: if you got any problem with core data or XML parsing, feel free... I would recommend you not to use the NSXMLParser (asynchronous and painful)